# how to insert second style element in echo

Tags: php, css

I am having this piece of code in which a style element is added.
How can I add a second style element in the same echo? per example: **color: orange;**

```
echo '<span class=\'Meta\' style=\'min-height:inherit\'>'.T('Read by: ').$out.'</span><br>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the rule separated by a semi-colon, in the same `style` attribute:

```
echo '<span class=\'Meta\' style=\'min-height:inherit; color:orange;\'>'.T('Read by: ').$out.'</span><br>';
```

I prefer using single and double quotes in combination, simpler to read and no need to escape quotes:

```
echo '<span class="Meta" style="min-height:inherit; color:orange;">'.T('Read by: ').$out.'</span><br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<span class="Meta" style="min-height:inherit;color:orange">'.T('Read by: ').$out.'</span><br>';
```

The code needs to be more clear.

No need to add a new `style` element.

You can add it as a new child to style with semi-colon `;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<span class=\'Meta\' style=\'min-height:inherit; color:green; \'>'.T('Read by: ').$out.'</span><br>';
```

You can add more CSS properties by separating it with a `;`

I would do the same thing differently, so as to make it more readable.

`echo '<span class="Meta" style="min-height:inherit; color:green;">'`. No need for extra `\`